# Wordpress behind reverse proxy login/form issues

Tags: wordpress, apache, cookies, reverse-proxy

I am having some issues with a wordpress site that we are trying to put behind a reverse proxy.

We have oldsite.com re-directing to newsite.com/blog

On new site we have a reverse proxy sitting at the Apache level with the below configuration:

`ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /blog http://www.oldsite.com.au
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://www.oldsite.com.au`

Almost everything is working, all the redirects appear correct and images and content is working fine.

The problem we are facing is that we cant login to the admin console, it just keeps re-directing to the login page.

Also we are unable to comments on articles we just get directed to a blank page with blog/wp-comments-post.php

We don't use ssl sign in so I don't think it relates to that for the admin log in. I think both issues may be related maybe via cookies or something, has anyone any ideas as to what happening and how to combat it?

Thanks in advance.

P